# list open windows

Tags: gnome, 22.04, ubuntu-gnome

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with gnome version 42.9 and Wayland.
I'm trying to list the open windows and get the name of the window on top in a python program but I can't find any command despite my research.
xdotool, wmctrl don't work
xlsclients, I don't know how to get the window titles.

can you please help me?

Comment: I find it unclear. Did anything crash? If nothing crashed, it's either `Alt`+`Tab` or the top-left Activities menu.

Comment: their is an error in my translation
I just want a list off all open windows and the title of the windows in the top

Comment: does [this Super User post](https://superuser.com/questions/176754/get-a-list-of-open-windows-in-linux) help?

Comment: I already read the article but no
wmctrl -l send any answer
xwininfo -root -children send too many information because of the complexity of gnome+mutter ...

Comment: $ xwininfo -root -children

xwininfo: Window id: 0x496 (the root window) (has no name)

  Root window id: 0x496 (the root window) (has no name)
  Parent window id: 0x0 (none)
     17 children:
     0x80028c "gnome-shell": ()  10x10+-100+-100  +-100+-100
     0x800006 "GNOME Shell": ()  1x1+-100+-100  +-100+-100
     0x600001 "ibus-x11": ("ibus-x11" "Ibus-x11")  10x10+10+10  +10+10
     0x200001 "gsd-xsettings": ("gsd-xsettings" "Gsd-xsettings")  10x10+10+10  +10+10
     0x800015 "mutter guard window": ()  1920x1080+0+0  +0+0


I don't know how to use this output

Comment: According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399753/how-to-get-a-list-of-active-windows-when-using-wayland `xwininfo` and `wmctrl` do not work with Wayland.  They suggest using `sed` and `jq`.

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: I I tried to develop a small extension but it wasn't very optimized.